# Changing screen brightness

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, hp, brightness

I have a hp pavilion dv6 with xubuntu installed. however there isn't a way to change the screen brightness, i tried the fn plus scroll keys to no avail, any ideas?

Comment: Same here. cannot change brightness with Fn + arrow keys.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 11):

Package name is xfce4-power-manager-plugins. Solved my brightness problem in xubuntu 10.04.2.

Comment: I'd give you a thousand +1s!

Comment: So I have this package installed, what should I do next?

Answer (score 7):

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

You can change:

- Brightness from 1 to 10.
- acpi_video0 or acpi_video1

Comment: I'm extrremely new to xubuntu, and I was wondering if it could be possible to assign this command to a shortcut key?

Comment: @Jiskya http://askubuntu.com/a/760958/357970

Answer (score 2):

XFCE has a panel applet for changing brightness, I don't remember if it's installed, so search in packages (e.g. in synaptic) for XFCE and brightness. Then right-click on the panel to add it.

Comment: After installing additional power manager package I could add a brightness applet to the panel

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your terminal
2. Type `sudo apt-get install xfce4-power-manager-plugins`
3. Enter your password and press y key to continue
4. Right-click on the panel, Panel-> Panel Preferences...
5. Come to the Items tab, click on Add new items button (+) and search for Power Manager Plugin
6. Select it and click on the Add button

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the following files in /etc/acpi/ directory

Download video_brightnessup.sh from [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/images/video_brightnessup.sh)

Download video_brightnessdown.sh from [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/images/video_brightnessdown.sh)

After replacing these scripts

No reboot or logout required, simply press your function combination on your laptop to change brightness. Try to press FN + Up/Down Arrow.

Comment: did absolutely nothing :/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, i unchecked "Power Manager" from "Application Autostart" list in `Settings -> Session and Startup` and added another application with this command `xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon` then i have not have this problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem as well.

What fixed it for me was adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the kernel boot line. For more information see [**Brightness not working on an HP Pavilion Dv6 with a ATI Radeon HD6770M**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162409/brightness-not-working-on-an-hp-pavilion-dv6-with-a-ati-radeon-hd6770m).

After doing this, I could change my brightness normally using the <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> keys.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was modifying the /etc/default/grub file.

Change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Then in a terminal `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

[More info here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `xgamma`. The default value is 1.0, higher is brighter, lower is darker.

Example `xgamma -gamma 0.9`.

Comment: not looking to change the gamma, i want to change the backlight brightness