# How do I change my keyboard shortcuts in xubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xubuntu

I am a new Xubuntu user. Earlier when using Gnome, I was able to configure several desktop shortcuts, particularly for navigation between workspaces.

But, now in Xubuntu, I cannot find those options.

Where can I find those options.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts are tucked away in your *Settings Manager - Window Manager - Keyboard*

[image]

Scroll down the list - you will see several workspace shortcuts, some defined with a shortcut and some awaiting to be defined.

Answer (score 23):

There are more available in Settings Editor in Settngs Manager, which can be launched from the command-line using:

```
xfce4-settings-editor
```

This will display:

[image: XFCE4 Settings Editor]

Comment: I tried changing my `left_workspace_key` to `<Super>Left` using the editor with sudo. Restarted and the shorcuts remain bound to `<Control><Alt>Left` any help? http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-10252014-012914pm.php

Comment: I just switched from Windows. This is so easy to use and navigate! SCREW YOU, REGEDIT! :D

Comment: this is not the answer.  I voted for the other one

Comment: this is editable through cli?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich I think so, see `xfconf-query -v -l -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts`

Answer (score 8):

### For Xfce 4.8 (Xubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Keyboard shortcuts are accessible from *Settings -> Settings Manager -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts*:

[image]

- Choose *"Add"* to add a command you need to assign to a shortcut.
  [image]
- In the window following *"Ok"* press the key combination you want to assign:
  [image]

Comment: What would I add here to make <Super> open the Application Menu?

Answer (score 7):

### Automate this with `xfconf-query`

If multiple machines require configuring keyboard shortcuts, this can be done without having to repeatedly open windows. Rather, use the very handy `xfconf-query` command in a `bash` script to `--set` a `--property` in `xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`.

Here is an example:

```
$ xfconf-query --create --channel xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts --property /commands/custom/XF86AudioMute --type string --set 'amixer -D pulse set Master 1+ toggle'
```

As a matter of fact, this is part of [my solution to restore the function of the mute button](https://askubuntu.com/a/423786/164341) in Xubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Works great if you are adding a new shortcut. If you however need to alter an existing one, you first have to delete it by the `--reset` option and create it again. Otherwise the running XFCE session will not pick it up.

Comment: How would one go about using a different button to bind the command to? For example CtrlAltUp? In other words, how did you know to use `/commands/custom/XF86AudioMute`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also play in a console with gedit and `/apps/metacity/keybinding_commands` or `/apps/metacity/global_keybindings`

Answer (score 1):

## Easy Way

[Heres a script](https://github.com/nappa300/Keybind/tree/master/xml/xfce4) that handles binding commands to keys cleanly in Xubuntu. Download keybind.c, compile it (example is given in readme in link) and simply run `./keybind "<keys to bind to>" "<command>"`

For example heres some I use:

```
./keybind "<Control><Alt>Delete" "gnome-system-monitor"

./keybind "<Control><Alt>Up" "xrandr -o inverted"
./keybind "<Control><Alt>Down" "xrandr -o normal"
./keybind "<Control><Alt>Right" "xrandr -o left"
./keybind "<Control><Alt>Left" "xrandr -o right"
```

Disclosure: I created the script.

## Slightly less Easy Way

If you're running a Xubuntu system and want to do it from the terminal it is a simple procedure too.

For debugging, here is where keybinding shortcuts are stored in XFCE4: `$ gedit ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`

Underlying Schema:
1) Remove existing commands bound to the binding keys 
2) Set new command to keys

```
1a) 
`xfconf-query --reset --channel xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts --property "/commands/custom/<Control><Alt>Down"`<br />
`xfconf-query --reset --channel xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts --property "/xfwm4/custom/<Control><Alt>Down"`<br />
2)
`xfconf-query --create --channel xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts --property "/commands/custom/<Control><Alt>Down" --type string --set 'gedit'`
```

**note** if you're binding to  key, ubuntu systems treat  and  equally and you will need to unbind any key bindings with in the above example `<Primary><Alt>Down`

Comment: Is that linked "script" really a C program, that just runs terminal commands, kind of like a more complicated shell script?