# How to change de "Minimize all windows" shortcut in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

i have xubuntu on my pc, and i want to minimize all the windows when i press Super+D.
Do yo know how can i do this? I've enter to the keybord shortcuts, but i don't know the "minimize all windows" command.

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The default is `Ctrl+Alt+D`. To change shortcuts try the answers on this post [How do I change my keyboard shortcuts in xubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90513/how-do-i-change-my-keyboard-shortcuts-in-xubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

1. Open System Settings (power icon in the top right) and select
   "Keyboard" (not "Keyboard Layout").
2. On the "Shortcuts" tab, select "Navigation" in the left menu.
3. Scroll down to find "Hide all normal windows".
4. Click the shortcut text to the right, and it will show "New
   accelerator".
5. Press Super+D and it will change.
6. Try it out.

Answer (score 3):

In Xubuntu:
Settings -> Window Manager -> Keyboard -> Show Desktop