# Is there a keyboard shortcut to take a screenshot that doesn't use the PrtScrn key?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce, chromebook, crouton

I am running Ubuntu on a Chromebook via Crouton.  As my keyboard does not have a Print Screen key, and I would like to take A screenshot, I am unsure of what to do.

I am using the Xfce interface, and I would like to take a screenshot of a LibreOffice drawing so as to change my background.

Comment: You can edit shortcut in Settings->Devices>Keyboard

Comment: "Devices" does not exist.

Comment: Its the last in left sidebar. May be we have different versions. So, I recommend to install `shutter` the advanced screenshot  program, choose capture window and select needed window in this program. It also can capture selected area of screen.

Comment: I hacave a prrrr

Comment: @leonid OP mentioned they use Xfce. What you suggested (viz. Settings->Devices>Keyboard) is for (later releases) of GNOME.

Comment: Your answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/90513/how-do-i-change-my-keyboard-shortcuts-in-xubuntu  and set the command to: `xfce4-screenshooter` to take screenshots.

Comment: If you're using the GUI only, mine wouldn't let me *edit* the shortcut trigger keys, but it was easy to copy the command, make a new shortcut with the same command, then press the keys to trigger the new shortcut (and optionally delete the old shortcut, or just leave it in case you find a PrtScn button later)